# I get this ridiculous value when reading IOS camera's lens position

Tags: ios, swift, camera

Using this code with the BuiltInWideAngleCamera in Swift on an iPhone XS MAX running iOS 12.1.2:

```
let lensPos: Float  = AVCaptureDevice.currentLensPosition;
lockCameraForSettings();
self.inputDevice?.setFocusModeLocked(lensPosition: LensPos, completionHandler: { (time) -> Void in})
unlockCameraForShooting();
```

results in a crash:

[AVCaptureDevice setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition:completionHandler:] The passed lensPosition -340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 is out-of-range [0, 1]'

The camera is running and visibly in focus on the screen preview. How is it possible for it to be in this configuration?

Inserting a constant value between 0-1 works, at least in that it does not throw an error.

Comment: welcome new user, you have some problem relating to the type being incorrect, mixup with floats, integers, etc etc.

Comment: Apple's doc says that AVCaptureDevice.currentLensPosition is a Float betwixt 0 and 1. If I do nothing but the first line shown above, then debug print lensPos, I get: "lens is at 3.4028235e+38"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean to use `.lensPosition` instead of `.currentLensPosition` which is a special constant representing the position of the lens. You can only access `.lensPosition` when you are referencing a instance of type `AVCaptureDevice`.

```
    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

    // Plus models and X's
    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera,
                                            for: .video, position: .back) {
        captureDevice = device
     // Single Lens devices.
    } else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                                                   for: .video, position: .back) {
        captureDevice = device
    } else {
        // No camera was found, is it broke?
        print("Missing expected back camera device.")
    }

    if let device = captureDevice {
        // We have a device, do something with it.
        print(device.lensPosition)
    }
```

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to convert lensPosition to cm for the focal distance? and where to look up for conversion table if one is needed? Thank you!